# Passive event listeners

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function loadMenuBasedScript() {}
var getMenuDependentValues="";
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("selectMenu").onchange = function() {
    menuSelected = this.value;
    loadMenuBasedScript(menuSelected, getMenuDependentValues);
  };
}, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <select id="selectMenu">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

If I click the menu icon, chrome shows a warning in the console:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

How to over overcome with simple `html` and `js`? I need the `value` based on the menu selected.

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md

Comment: What menu icon? I had to add a function and a var to have a [mcve]

Comment: running the code I provided, a box appears with `One`. If I click there(to make change it to `two`), I get the warning (in the console of chrome).

Comment: Having the same problem with a select... Did you solve this?

Comment: No. I tried other browsers (firefox dev, canary, opera), and they are not showing that warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a problem with Chrome. It happens even with only `<select></select>` and no event listeners. Chrome automatically logs whenever a scroll-blocking event occurs .
Using Chrome's DevTools, I checked that there is no mousewheel listeners on the select box, and it still happens.

I suggest turning off 'Verbose' in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) or do something, that has to occur, before the event ends, you should use the `passive` option in [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which doesn't block the event while your listener executes.

So your code would look like:

```js
function loadMenuBasedScript() {}
var getMenuDependentValues = "";
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("selectMenu").addEventListener('change', function() {
    menuSelected = this.value;
    loadMenuBasedScript(menuSelected, getMenuDependentValues);
  }, {
    passive: true
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <select id="selectMenu">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```